# Wants to concatenate tow 3D matrix (10,61,1)

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I try to concatenate two numpy arrays with 3 dimensions.

I Actually tried with `np.append` and `np.concatenate`.
The dimensions of what I want to concatenate are

`((10, 61, 1) (1, 0, 0))`.

So I want to save the same structure. The final results is something with this size ( ,) So Python put everything on the same dimension

```
matrix_results_final = np.empty((1,0,0), float)
vec_y_labels_final = np.empty((1), int)

dict_minmax_scall = searchMinMaxValuesRawDataByElectrode(raw_data)
for electrode_number in electrode_numbers:
    #... Some code

    matrix_results_final = np.append(matrix_results_final, matrix_results)
```

Where the matrix_results_final is `(1,0,0)` and the matrix_results (10,61,1)
So I want to wave (matrix_results_final (10,61,1) in the first iteration, (20,61,1) on the second,...

I don't have any error message.

Answer (score 0):

if i understood you correctly you want to append some data in a loop like:

```py
import numpy as np

arr = np.random.rand(10,61,1)

for i in range(3):

    print(arr.shape)

    arr2 = np.random.rand(10,61,1)
    arr = np.concatenate([arr,arr2],axis=0)

print(arr.shape)
```

```py
(10, 61, 1)
(20, 61, 1)
(30, 61, 1)
(40, 61, 1)
```

note that it would be more effective to first assign a empty array with the **final** shape and then fill it (so we don't have to find new memory space - because the array doesn't change the size - in each iteration)

```py
arr = np.zeros((40,61,1))

for i in range(4):

    ii = i * 10
    arr[ii:ii+10,:,:] = np.random.rand(10,61,1)
```